# Buffer Argument is NULL

Tags: c++, halide

I am new to Halide and was given a image processing Pipeline. I am trying to understand this pipe line by printing values. Following the tutorial from https://halide-lang.org/tutorials/tutorial_lesson_04_debugging_2.html, I tried to print the values. It is giving me 2 types of errors.

1.**Buffer argument in_patch is NULL** for **transform.realize(512,256,3)**.

2.**'Halide::Internal::GeneratorBase::Input > {aka class Halide::GeneratorInput >}' has no member named 'realize'** for 
    **TsTw_tran_h.realize(3,3)**;

I am assuming that for the second error, it has something to do with not using the variables x and y.

Is there a way to work around the first error?

Any Help wil be highly Appreciated.

Thanks in advance

```
#include "Halide.h"

namespace {

using namespace Halide;

///////////////////////// We will define a generator to auto-schedule.
class AutoScheduled : public Halide::Generator<AutoScheduled> {
public:
    Input<Buffer<uint8_t>>   in_patch   {"in_patch"   , 3};
    Input<Buffer<float>>   ctrl_pts_h {"ctrl_pts_h" , 2};      
    Input<Buffer<float>>   weights_h  {"weights_h"  , 2};       
    Input<Buffer<float>>   rev_tone_h {"rev_tone_h" , 2};       
    Input<Buffer<float>>   TsTw_tran_h{"TsTw_tran_h", 2};       
    Input<Buffer<float>>   coefs_h    {"coefs_h"    , 2};       

    Output<Buffer<uint8_t>> processed {"processed"  , 3};

    void generate() {  
    Var x("x"), y("y"), c("c");

        Func scale("scale");
        scale(x,y,c) = cast<float>(in_patch(x,y,c))/256;

        // Color map and white balance transform

        Func transform("transform");
            transform(x,y,c) = select(
                // Perform matrix multiplication, set min of 0
                c == 0, scale(x,y,0)      * TsTw_tran_h(0,0)
                      + scale(x,y,1)      * TsTw_tran_h(1,0)
                      + scale(x,y,2)      * TsTw_tran_h(2,0),
                c == 1, scale(x,y,0)      * TsTw_tran_h(0,1)
                      + scale(x,y,1)      * TsTw_tran_h(1,1)
                      + scale(x,y,2)      * TsTw_tran_h(2,1),
                        scale(x,y,0)      * TsTw_tran_h(0,2)
                      + scale(x,y,1)      * TsTw_tran_h(1,2)
                      + scale(x,y,2)      * TsTw_tran_h(2,2) );
                      scale.compute_root();
                      transform.trace_stores();
                      scale.trace_stores();
                      TsTw_tran_h.realize(3,3);
                      transform.realize(512,256,3);

        processed(x, y, c) = cast<uint8_t>( min( max( transform(x,y,c) * 255, 0), 255 ) ); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the problem was with the schedule. All the functions were being inlined because of the auto schedule. Once the auto_schedule was disabled, It worked.